# Why is this json value not a PHP array key?

Tags: php, json

When parsing the json below, the PHP statement:

```
if (array_key_exists($json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"][$b][$a])) {
```

never evaluates to true despite that "Demo" is a "key" as shown from the print_r statement.

**What am I doing wrong on how I'm testing to see if "Demo" or "Live" actually exists in the json?** (one or the other or both may be there for any given record)

Thank you.

Json:

```
{
  "MinimumVersion": "20191101",
  "Guids": {
    "0ebe7e53-12fc-4f8f-a873-4872fe30bbee": {
      "Broke": {
        "Yes": {
          "Demo" : { "Expires" : "" },
          "Live" : { "Expires" : "" }
        },
        "No": {
          "Demo" : { "Expires" : "20191104" },
          "Live" : { "Expries" : "" }
        }
      },
      "Message": "You need to upgrade to the latest version."
    }
  }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("json.txt");
$json_a = json_decode($string,true);

$g = "0ebe7e53-12fc-4f8f-a873-4872fe30bbee";
$b = "No";
$a = "Demo";

echo "G: \"" . $g . "\"<br>";
echo "B: \"" . $b . "\"<br>";
echo "A: \"" . $a . "\"<br>";

if (is_array($json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"][$b][$a])) {
    #This next line prints Array ([0] => Expires )
    print_r(array_keys($json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"][$b][$a]));
} else {
    echo "Test: false";
}

if (array_key_exists($g,$json_a["Guids"])) {
    echo ("true1");
    if (array_key_exists($b,$json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"])) {
        echo ("true2");
        if (array_key_exists($json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"][$b][$a])) {
            #this never evaluates to true. Why? "Demo" is a "key" as shown from the print_r results statement above.
            echo "Value:\"" . $json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"][$b][$a] . "\"<br>";
        }
    }    
}

?>
```

Comment: `array_key_exist` need two arguments: the key and the array: [see](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) but you do not give the key `Demo`

Comment: Please go enable proper PHP error reporting, so that PHP can tell you about such mistakes by itself.

Comment: @GrenierJ: OMG! Such a STUPID mistake on my part! Thank you for the second set of eyes and spotting that.

Comment: Why is/was this question voted down? The OP posted a legit question asking what they were doing wrong along with the necessary examples. So the OP forgot to include a parameter in the api call, and probably missed it from staring at the screen for hours on end wondering. Almost all programmers have been there / done that. That doesn't deserve a vote down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) properly for that particular case (you use it correctly elsewhere). The correct usage is

```
array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )
```

so for what you want to check, you should use

```
array_key_exists($a, $json_a["Guids"][$g]["Broke"][$b]);
```